# How to pass date and month in 'YYYY-MM' format as partition argument in Pig

Tags: shell, apache-pig

```
a = LOAD '$hivedb.hiveorders' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = FILTER a by order_id >= $currval;

store b into '$hivedb.orders_part' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer('order_month=SUBSTRING(order_date,0,7)');
```

I get the following error :

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1115: Invalid
>   partition column specification. order_month=SUBSTRING(order_date,0,7)

If I pass any hardcoded value, it works fine. How to pass values to order_month depending on the order_date ... ?

Comment: try not the pass any value, however make sure that string you want to create as partition is part of column.

Comment: Nope, it did not worked that way...

Comment: Still looking for solution, if anyone can help !

Comment: I think what @gaurang-shah suggested above should work.  After filter, add `C = FOREACH B GENERATE *, SUBSTRING(order_date,0,7) as order_month; `  Argument to Loader/Storer has to be fixed at compile time.